# Laravel 5.2 : Slightly different ways of declaring "middlewares"?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware

In `Laravel 5.2`, below are two different kinds of declarations for `middlewares` in Groups.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
});
```

I've seen these two different things through Googling. What is the difference between them please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    });`

This uses only web middleware. If you want to use multiple middlewares, you have to write like this:

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
});`

Then you can add another middleware, for example admin middleware:

`Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'admin']], function () {
});`

Anyway, if you want to use only a middleware i think is better write the first.

Comment: So the two declarations in my example are the same? I mean, if i use "any" of them, then they work the say way?

Comment: Yes, both work exactly same. Choice is base on the number of middlewares you want to use.